# Missing queues from RabbitMQ Metricbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, rabbitmq, metricbeat

It looks like only a fraction of the queues on my RabbitMQ cluster are making it into Elasticsearch via Metricbeat.

When I query RabbitMQ's `/api/overview`, I see 887 queues reported:

```
object_totals: {
consumers: 517,
queues: 887,
exchanges: 197,
connections: 305,
channels: 622
},
```

When I query RabbitMQ's `/api/queues` (which is what Metricbeat hits), I count 887 queues there as well.

When I get a unique count of the field `rabbitmq.queue.name` in Elasticsearch, I am seeing only 309 queues.

---

I don't see anything in the debug output that stands out to me. It's just the usual INFO level startup messages, followed by the publish information:

```
root@rabbitmq:/etc/metricbeat# metricbeat -e
2019-06-24T21:13:33.692Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:571    Home path: [/usr/share/metricbeat] Config path: [/etc/metricbeat] Data path: [/var/lib/metricbeat] Logs path: [/var/log/metricbeat]
2019-06-24T21:13:33.692Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:579    Beat ID: xxx
2019-06-24T21:13:33.692Z    INFO    [index-management.ilm]  ilm/ilm.go:129  Policy name: metricbeat-7.1.1
2019-06-24T21:13:33.692Z    INFO    [seccomp]   seccomp/seccomp.go:116  Syscall filter successfully installed
2019-06-24T21:13:33.692Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:827    Beat info   {"system_info": {"beat": {"path": {"config": "/etc/metricbeat", "data": "/var/lib/metricbeat", "home": "/usr/share/metricbeat", "logs": "/var/log/metricbeat"}, "type": "metricbeat", "uuid": "xxx"}}}
2019-06-24T21:13:33.692Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:836    Build info  {"system_info": {"build": {"commit": "3358d9a5a09e3c6709a2d3aaafde628ea34e8419", "libbeat": "7.1.1", "time": "2019-05-23T13:23:10.000Z", "version": "7.1.1"}}}
2019-06-24T21:13:33.692Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:839    Go runtime info {"system_info": {"go": {"os":"linux","arch":"amd64","max_procs":4,"version":"go1.11.5"}}}
[...]
2019-06-24T21:13:33.694Z    INFO    [beat]  instance/beat.go:872    Process info    {"system_info": {"process": {"capabilities": {"inheritable":null,"permitted":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend","audit_read"],"effective":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend","audit_read"],"bounding":["chown","dac_override","dac_read_search","fowner","fsetid","kill","setgid","setuid","setpcap","linux_immutable","net_bind_service","net_broadcast","net_admin","net_raw","ipc_lock","ipc_owner","sys_module","sys_rawio","sys_chroot","sys_ptrace","sys_pacct","sys_admin","sys_boot","sys_nice","sys_resource","sys_time","sys_tty_config","mknod","lease","audit_write","audit_control","setfcap","mac_override","mac_admin","syslog","wake_alarm","block_suspend","audit_read"],"ambient":null}, "cwd": "/etc/metricbeat", "exe": "/usr/share/metricbeat/bin/metricbeat", "name": "metricbeat", "pid": 30898, "ppid": 30405, "seccomp": {"mode":"filter","no_new_privs":true}, "start_time": "2019-06-24T21:13:33.100Z"}}}
2019-06-24T21:13:33.694Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:280    Setup Beat: metricbeat; Version: 7.1.1
2019-06-24T21:13:33.694Z    INFO    [publisher] pipeline/module.go:97   Beat name: metricbeat
2019-06-24T21:13:33.694Z    INFO    instance/beat.go:391    metricbeat start running.
2019-06-24T21:13:33.694Z    INFO    cfgfile/reload.go:150   Config reloader started
2019-06-24T21:13:33.694Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:117  Starting metrics logging every 30s
[...]
2019-06-24T21:13:43.696Z    INFO    filesystem/filesystem.go:57 Ignoring filesystem types: sysfs, rootfs, ramfs, bdev, proc, cpuset, cgroup, cgroup2, tmpfs, devtmpfs, configfs, debugfs, tracefs, securityfs, sockfs, dax, bpf, pipefs, hugetlbfs, devpts, ecryptfs, fuse, fusectl, pstore, mqueue, autofs
2019-06-24T21:13:43.696Z    INFO    fsstat/fsstat.go:59 Ignoring filesystem types: sysfs, rootfs, ramfs, bdev, proc, cpuset, cgroup, cgroup2, tmpfs, devtmpfs, configfs, debugfs, tracefs, securityfs, sockfs, dax, bpf, pipefs, hugetlbfs, devpts, ecryptfs, fuse, fusectl, pstore, mqueue, autofs
2019-06-24T21:13:44.696Z    INFO    pipeline/output.go:95   Connecting to backoff(async(tcp://xxx))
2019-06-24T21:13:44.711Z    INFO    pipeline/output.go:105  Connection to backoff(async(tcp://xxx)) established
2019-06-24T21:14:03.696Z    INFO    [monitoring]    log/log.go:144  Non-zero metrics in the last 30s    {"monitoring": {"metrics": {"beat":{"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":130,"time":{"ms":131}},"total":{"ticks":1960,"time":{"ms":1965},"value":1960},"user":{"ticks":1830,"time":{"ms":1834}}},"handles":{"limit":{"hard":1048576,"soft":1024},"open":12},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"xxx","uptime":{"ms":30030}},"memstats":{"gc_next":30689808,"memory_alloc":21580680,"memory_total":428076400,"rss":79917056}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":0},"reloads":2},"output":{"events":{"acked":7825,"batches":11,"total":7825},"read":{"bytes":66},"type":"logstash","write":{"bytes":870352}},"pipeline":{"clients":4,"events":{"active":313,"published":8138,"retry":523,"total":8138},"queue":{"acked":7825}}},"metricbeat":{"rabbitmq":{"connection":{"events":2987,"failures":10,"success":2977},"exchange":{"events":1970,"success":1970},"node":{"events":10,"success":10},"queue":{"events":3130,"failures":10,"success":3120}},"system":{"cpu":{"events":2,"success":2},"filesystem":{"events":7,"success":7},"fsstat":{"events":1,"success":1},"load":{"events":2,"success":2},"memory":{"events":2,"success":2},"network":{"events":4,"success":4},"process":{"events":18,"success":18},"process_summary":{"events":2,"success":2},"socket_summary":{"events":2,"success":2},"uptime":{"events":1,"success":1}}},"system":{"cpu":{"cores":4},"load":{"1":0.48,"15":0.28,"5":0.15,"norm":{"1":0.12,"15":0.07,"5":0.0375}}}}}}
```

I think if there were a problem getting the queue, I should see an error in the logs above as per https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/metricbeat/module/rabbitmq/queue/data.go#L94-L104

Here's the `metricbeat.yml`:

```
metricbeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: true
  reload.period: 10s

setup.template.settings:
  index.number_of_shards: 1
  index.codec: best_compression

name: metricbeat

fields:
  environment: development

processors:
- add_cloud_metadata: ~

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["xxx"]
```

Here's the `modules.d/rabbitmq.yml`:

```
- module: rabbitmq
  metricsets: ["node", "queue", "connection", "exchange"]
  enabled: true
  period: 2s
  hosts: ["xxx"]
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
```

Comment: Quick guess, can you check you don't have identically named queues in distinct vhosts? If this were the case, your unique count on rabbitmq.queue.name would indeed be lower than the total number of queues.

Comment: There are a few duplicates, but not that many. If I query Elasticsearch for data associated with one of the missing queues, I will get no results.

Comment: And the rights of the user configured in metricbeat give him access to all the vhosts? Are the missing queues spread throughout the vhosts or isolated to one/a few?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by upgrading Elastic Stack from 7.1.1 to 7.2.0.